# Object of class could not be converted to string with Symfony Form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a problem with one of my forms. When I submit it, I have this error : `Object of class ... could not be converted to string`.

I already looked at some other cases like mine but I really don't know what is wrong. Method toString doesn't exist in my entity but I never needed it for all my other forms which look like this one.

My form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('nom', TextType::class,['label' => 'Nom de la colle'])
    ->add('collesEnfants', CollectionType::class,
        ['label' => false,
        'entry_type' => SousColleFormType::class,
        'required' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'PACES\ColleBundle\Entity\Colle'
    ]);
}
```

SousColleFormType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('matiere', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'PACESColleBundle:Matiere',
            'attr' => ['class'=> 'matiere'],
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une matière',
            'mapped' => false])
        ->add('nom', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'PACESColleBundle:Colle',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'colles'],
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'label' => false,
            'group_by' => 'matiere',
            'required' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'choose.colle'])
        ->add('ordre', IntegerType::class,[
            'attr'=>['class'=>'ordre'],
            'required' => true,
            'label' => false]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => 'PACES\ColleBundle\Entity\Colle'
    ]);
}
```

Colle entity :

```
class Colle
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Colle", mappedBy="colleMere", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"ordre" = "asc"})
 */
private $collesEnfants;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Colle", inversedBy="collesEnfants", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="colleMere_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $colleMere;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $nom;

{........}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PACES\ColleBundle\Entity\Matiere", inversedBy="colles", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="matiere_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $matiere;

/**
 * Cet attribut sert aux 'super colles' qui sont le résultat d'une fusion de colles d'une même UE
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="ordre", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $ordre;
```

Comment: Quick 'n dirty: Add `public function __toString() { return 'I CAUSE THIS ISSUE';} `to your entity ... see where inside the rendered HTML it appears (choice-label, choice-value, ... ) then add your findings to the question.

Comment: I tried your way. I don't know why but the form is creating a new Colle entity with collesEnfants field (with name = I CAUSE THIS ISSUE). Normal behaviour is to setColleMere of selected collesEnfants to the newly created Colle Entity.